# HTML Text before copy

Tags: javascript, html

I found a code online that allows me to copy text to clipboard but I made a button and I don't want it to say Server IP. Here because that's what the code will copy I want it to say Copy Server IP and then it will copy the Server IP Here section, If someone could help I would be great full thanks.

```
<a id="demo" class="button cta-button" onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML)">Server Ip Here</a>
<script>
  function copyToClipboard(text) {
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
  }
</script>
```

Where it says Server IP Here it would be my server IP but I'd like it to say ~Copy Server IP Instead of it just showing the IP and clicking it to copy.

Comment: Please make an effort to understand what you're doing (at least try and understand the programming language!) first..

Comment: All I could see is Server IP, Copy, Server IP. `:/` meh.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** *Edit 2 should answer to the question*

```
<a id="demo" class="button cta-button" onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML)">
Server Ip Here
</a>
```

Everything between `"` is rendered as text.

Example:

```
var text="value";
console.log(text); //Will render "value"
console.log("text"); //Will render "text"
```

`copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML)` is then executed with arg `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML` which is a string here.

**Case 1**
Your `<a>` tags displays the value of your IP server

`onclick="copyToClipboard("+document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML+")"`

**Case 2**
Your `<a>` tags hides the IP of the server

```
var ip = "ip address";  //In your javascript file
```

`onclick="copyToClipboard("+ip+")"`

*Warning: Your ip value must be declared in the top of your HTML file in `<script>` tag or a file before the html is rendered in your body, else `ip` value is null and your `<a>` tag will have a wrong value `onclick="copyToClipboard()"`*

**EDIT 2**
Considering the script part okay

```
<a id="demo" class="button cta-button" onclick="copyToClipboard('192.168.1.1')">
Click here to copy ip
</a>
```

`document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML` gives you everything inside your tags `<a id="demo">` tags, so in your example it was "Server Ip Here". However that is not what you were expecting, so you can change it by the value of your IP server.

This works:

```
<script>
    function copyToClipboard(text) {
         window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
      }
</script>

<a id="demo" class="button cta-button" onclick="copyToClipboard('192.168.1.1')">
     Click here to copy ip
</a>
```

About `<a>` tags, give a try to the *Try it yourself* to understand how do they work
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I'm not advanced in this but i'll try give an example of how i'm trying to get it <a id="demo" class="button cta-button" onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML)" Click here to copy ip >
127.0.0.1
</a>

Comment: You see where i put the click here to copy ip then put the ip where it will copy it i'm trying to add the text click here to copy ip pretty much because atm it's displaying the ip in the button...

Comment: Hold on, let me make you a better answer, I won't get enough with thoses characters

Comment: thanks it worked <3

Comment: No problem, don't forget mark the answer